# Buddypress profile pictures sync across Wordpress Multisite Network

Tags: buddypress, multisite-user-management

I am setting up a Multisite Network project. All websites will be handled with SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL. One of the websites will have BuddyPress, it will also serve as an entry point to the network. User will register through buddypress.domain.com and from there it will have access to other sites (portals, shops...)

I managed to setup user sync, so username and passwords are stored networkwide, but the problem is profile picture.

When user ads profile picture through BuddyPress it won't sync on other sites, so if they leave a comment on the portal site, their avatar is empty.

Is there a way to syncronize BP user avatar across the entire network of websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activating multisite I installed and network activated BuddyPress. I also added this line to wp-config.php: define ( 'BP_ROOT_BLOG', 2 ); where 2 is ID of your communitycommunity.mysite.com

That way BP is accessible from an entire network, but profiles are handled only from the network site.

On network sub site users update their profile info, pictures etc and the changes are reflected across the network.

Answer (score 1):

Filter `bp_core_avatar_upload_path` and `bp_core_avatar_url` to use a global path/url rather than a site-specific one.

For example: https://github.com/mlaa/humanities-commons/blob/578b0c071956707cebe229b6a03b6cab2e3462d4/humanities-commons.php#L1089

Comment: Thanks for the help, in the end I went with this option: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252895/buddypress-and-wordpress-on-different-subdomains-with-the-same-database