# Buddypress and Wordpress on different subdomains with the same database?

Tags: buddypress

What I'm wanting to do is have my blog on blog.mysite.com and my buddypress on community.mysite.com. Is it possible to have that, but them share the same database? Like when you log onto the community.mysite.com site, you can comment and all that on blog.mysite.com? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most definitely YES, this is possible:

1. You need to activate [multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) with subdomains support:
2. One of the sites needs to be on root domain. I suggest blog.
3. Install and network activate BuddyPress
4. Add this line to wp-config.php: define ( 'BP_ROOT_BLOG', 2 ); where 2 is ID of your communitycommunity.mysite.com

And that's about it.